# How are bidirectional streams handled for TCP disconnection exceptions in gRPC?

Tags: go, grpc

In a bidirectional streaming setup in gRPC, if one party terminates the TCP connection, for instance, if the server abruptly crashes and restarts, how can the client re-establish the connection? Do we need to handle this manually, or does gRPC itself have mechanisms to address this situation?

proto file :

```
service LiveService{
    rpc Dial(LiveReq)returns(stream LiveResp){}
}

message LiveReq{

}

message LiveResp{
    string rtmp = 1;
}
```

client service:

```
func handler() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    req := rpc.LiveReq{}
    dial, err := slave.GetLiveClient().Dial(ctx, &req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for true {

        resp, err := dial.Recv() // tcp stop ,server stop
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Print(err)
        }else{
            fmt.Print(resp)
        }
    }
}
```

how to recover connection?

--------------------------re-edit---------------------------
I did this, check out the link
1.https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/5507

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66359526/11810946) answer your question? (i.e. the connection will be re-established automatically but it's up to you to re-establish the stream).

Comment: @Brits Thanks your reply。I know the TCP re-establishment method, but I want to restore the rpc stream. Can I only execute "slave.GetLiveClient().Dial(ctx, &req)" again, and can't it be automatically restored?

Comment: Correct - if the stream dies (whether due to a network issue or something else) you need to make an RPC call to re-establish it.

Comment: @Brits look https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/5507   and https://gist.github.com/sosborne1/9440ac18a5798cea91873caae0ccf1bf#file-interceptor_test-go-L52-L54 . I dit this

Comment: That just moves the reconnection logic into an Interceptor. This is fine if it achieves your goal; personally I'd rather handle this where the stream is managed because restarting a stream may have unexpected impacts e.g.. loss of data from while the connection was down.